# How to populate data from xml to listbox in Windows Phone?

Tags: xml, windows, windows-phone-7, mobile, listbox

i want to populate this xml

```
<head xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <arm>
        <fingers>
            <middle>1</middle>
            <middle>2</middle>
        </fingers>   
        <fingers>
            <middle>3</middle>
            <middle>4</middle>
        </fingers>   
    </arm>
</head>
```

i want the file this data in a listbox

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display list of middle tag content in ListBox you cant try to do it this way :

```
var xml = @"<head xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">
            <arm>
                <fingers>
                    <middle>1</middle>
                    <middle>2</middle>
                </fingers>   
                <fingers>
                    <middle>3</middle>
                    <middle>4</middle>
                </fingers>   
            </arm>
        </head>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace xmlNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/";
var middles = from middle in doc.Descendants(xmlNamespace + "middle") select middle.Value;
MyListBox.ItemsSource = middles;
```

The code above using linq-to-xml to query only value inside `<middle>` tags. And then display the query result in `MyListBox`.

Comment: what if there is another tag ? after the middle ? example <first> and i want to display it also ?